# Can we take over the air backup of Applications, Call Log, SMS, MMS, Bookmarks, Alarms, Dictionary on an iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, backup, icloud

My app need to take backup of user's iPhone's almost entire data to iCloud.

Can we access the call log, SMS, MMS etc. databases of iPhone just as iCloud does internally while backing up programmatically?

Is there some means to give user option list for data he wants to backup to iCloud in our app and backup only that data instead of all data programmatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are referring to a non-jail broken device then in a word, no. An app cannot access data outside of its own sandbox

Answer (score 0):

Apple can't allow to access and change SMS and log associated database. If you have jailbreak iPhone then you can access database using following path.

> /var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db

- For development level you can access it but your application wan't get approve from iTune store.

Answer (score 0):

**It is not possible to get SMS/Call Log/MMS detail.**

Your application only access those data which can be supplies by **Apple's public API**.

Your application can not access data outside of **Sandbox** other than public API.

Yes, if your device is **jail-broken** and you can use hack like direct url to database.

But if you do so your application will never approve by **App Store**.

Please read **[App Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)**